# Angular route to a URL outside the base href

Tags: angular, angular-routing

When a service in our Angular app performs a HTTP request, we want to direct a user to the login page.

Here's our setup:

- https://foo.bar/ui        <-- our angular app, at 'base-href=/ui'
- https://foo.bar/login     <-- our login page, different app entirely

Here's what we're trying:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceHelper {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    public handleError<T>(result?: T): (error: any) => Observable<T> {
        {
            return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    // Direct the user to login
                    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                }
                console.error(error);
                return of(result as T);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that on 401, the browser gets directed to `https://foo.bar/ui/login`.  We run the app with 'base-href=/ui' in our angular.json.  Our login app is a different system, outside that base-href.

Is there any good way to tell Angular's router to redirect the user at an absolute URL on the same server, outside the base-href?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the `router` is for internal routes only. To navigate to an external route from the app, I would use the `Window` object. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1226718/7365461

Comment: @AliF50 I think you're right.  I could get the browser's address bar to show the right URL by trying ```this.router.navigateByUrl('/../login');```.  But even that wouldn't work, seemingly b/c it was an external route.  `window.location.href = '/../login'` seems to work.  If you write an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular router is only for internal routes of the application. To navigate to an external route from the app, I would use the Window object. [Check it out here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1226718/7365461)

Comment: This solved my issue by using `window.location.href = '/../login';` instead of the `router` service.  Note the `/../` which let me traverse up a directory.

Answer (score -1):

use HTTP interceptor and intercept the URL in the request object.
If the URL contains "login" as a substring, replace the URL with `https://foo.bar/login`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50856471/9462470) could be helpful