# Adding sort to table headers doesn't work - ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Angular template project

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to modify ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Angular template project.

In "Fetch data", I would like to be able to sort rows based on any column and direction.

I'm trying to do that with an example from [Angulat materials](https://material.angular.io/components/sort/examples), but it doesn't work.

The table does not appear, there are errors shown in the [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCbW6.png).

Could someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

I will be grateful for any help. I'm stuck for good.

fetch_data.component.ts code:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Sort } from '@angular/material/sort'


export interface WeatherForecast {
  date: string;
  temperatureC: number;
  temperatureF: number;
  summary: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html'
})

export class FetchDataComponent {
  public forecasts: WeatherForecast[];

  sortedData: WeatherForecast[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(baseUrl + 'weatherforecast').subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
      this.sortedData = this.forecasts.slice();
    }, error => console.error(error));

  }

  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    const data = this.forecasts.slice();
    if (!sort.active || sort.direction === '') {
      this.sortedData = data;
      return;
    }

    this.sortedData = data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (sort.active) {
        case 'date': return compare(a.date, b.date, isAsc);
        case 'temperatureC': return compare(a.temperatureC, b.temperatureC, isAsc);
        case 'temperatureF': return compare(a.temperatureF, b.temperatureF, isAsc);
        case 'summary': return compare(a.summary, b.summary, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}


function compare(a: number | string, b: number | string, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

fetch_data.component.html code:

```
<h1 id="tableLabel">Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<p *ngIf="!forecasts"><em>Loading...</em></p>

<table matSort (matSortChange) ="sortData($event)" class='table table-striped' aria-labelledby="tableLabel" *ngIf="forecasts">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th mat-sort-header="date">Date</th>
      <th mat-sort-header="temperatureC">Temp. (C)</th>
      <th mat-sort-header="temperatureF">Temp. (F)</th>
      <th mat-sort-header="summary">Summary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let forecast of sortedData">
      <td>{{ forecast.date }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureC }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.temperatureF }}</td>
      <td>{{ forecast.summary }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

app.module.ts code:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { FetchWeatherComponent } from './fetch-weather/fetch-weather.component';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MatSortModule,
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    FetchWeatherComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-weather', component: FetchWeatherComponent },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Could you please show how your `app.module.ts` looks like?

Comment: I think you have not added the services inside the provider's array of your app.module.ts because your error clearly states that no provider for  changedetectionref

Comment: @SumedhDeshpande I enclose app.module.ts code. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: @ivndsky I enclose app.module.ts code. I'd appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) this line might be the cause of the problem i think you should use an interceptor.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735655/how-do-i-set-the-baseurl-for-angular-httpclient